# Class not returning one of it's functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

When I run the following code without it being wrapped in a class, both functions do exactly what's expected, which should be obvious from the code provided below.

However, once I put them into a class together only the `getPass` function actually returns a value. I expect two lines to be printed, one with the `random string(password)` and one with the encrypted `string(password)`.

What am I missing here? I have tried including `self` in front of the variables in the `encryptPasswd` function, I've tried including `encryptPasswd` in the constructor (with `self` in front of it) and many other combos of similar tactics. I cannot figure out why it won't return the encrypted string. Please help. Here is the code (btw, the `sqlite3` library is imported for later use):

```py
import string
import secrets
import sqlite3
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


class generateEncyptedPasswd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = int(input("Enter the length of password: "))
        self.password = self.getPass(self.length)
        self.passwdInBytes = str.encode(self.password)
        self.encryptPasswd
        print(self.password)

    def getPass(self, length):
        return "".join(
            secrets.choice(
                string.ascii_uppercase
                + string.ascii_lowercase
                + string.digits
                + string.punctuation
            )
            for x in range(length)
        )

    def encryptPasswd(self, password):
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        cipher = Fernet(key)
        passwd = self.passwdInBytes
        encryptedPasswd = cipher.encrypt(self.passwd)
        print(self.encryptedPasswd)

generateEncyptedPassw()
```

Comment: `self.encryptPasswd` does nothing.  You need parentheses to make that an actual method call - and you need to supply the required `password` parameter to make it a valid call.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, and class names the `CamelCase` style. Looking at the current design of your program, I don't think using a class is necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I should work on being better about following casing convention. I also decided not to put this into a class, but ended up with too many global variables in an effort to get a decrypt function working. I am still having trouble with it. I keep getting "bytes object has no attribute 'decrypt' when i try to decrypt  using the variable that contains the encrypted string. I will likely make another post asking for help with this. It is getting frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really running your `encryptPasswd` in your constructor. 
Change your `self.encryptPasswd` to `self.encryptPasswd()` to call your method

You'd also want to change your

```
encryptedPasswd = cipher.encrypt(self.passwd
```

to

```
self.encryptedPasswd = cipher.encrypt(self.passwd)
```

Since you want the variable to be a class variable

Working code example would be

```
import string
import secrets
import sqlite3
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet


class generateEncyptedPasswd:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = int(input("Enter the length of password: "))
        self.password = self.getPass(self.length)
        self.passwdInBytes = str.encode(self.password)
        self.encryptPasswd()
        print(self.password)

    def getPass(self, length):
        return "".join(
            secrets.choice(
                string.ascii_uppercase
                + string.ascii_lowercase
                + string.digits
                + string.punctuation
            )
            for x in range(length)
        )

    def encryptPasswd(self):
        key = Fernet.generate_key()
        cipher = Fernet(key)
        passwd = self.passwdInBytes
        self.encryptedPasswd = cipher.encrypt(passwd)
        print(self.encryptedPasswd)


generateEncyptedPasswd()
```

Comment: Thank you! I also had to add `self` in front of `passwd = self.passwdInBytes` but you're help got me there! It's always something silly like missing parenthesis lol. I spent a couple hours trying to figure this out, reading documentation etc, how I missed that is beyond me.

Comment: I do notice that it actually prints the encrypted password before the clear text password, which is opposite what I expected, but sufficient, as I was just trying to make sure the code was working. However, for future reference, is there any insight into how one would determine in which order they would be printed? I assumed because the call for printing clear text came first in the code that it would be printed first in the output.

Comment: `self.encryptPasswd()` In your constructor is being run before your print statement. 
You could move your print up, or simple move your `print(self.encryptedPasswd)` to the bottom of your constructor

Answer (score 0):

When you define a class you have to call the functions either through the `__init__` method, or through the class object:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print("in constructor")

    def bar(self):
        print("in function")
```

If you do:

```
Foo()
```

Only `in constructor` prints. You want to do either of the following:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print("in constructor")
        self.bar() # NOTICE HERE

    def bar(self):
        print("in function")
```

Above will call `bar()` when you initialize the object via `Foo()`, or:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print("in constructor")

    def bar(self):
        print("in function")


f = Foo()
f.bar()
```

Above will call the function `bar` after the object has been initialized. Both will output:

```
in constructor
in function
```